# Always On Architecture Question

Tags: sql-server, availability-groups

I have three servers Server1, Server2 and Server3. Server1 contains DB1, DB2 and similarly Server2 Contains DB3 and DB4. Can I use Server3 to host the AG groups of Server1 and Server2.

I have drawn a very bad picture below my apologies :). 
AG1 and AG2 represents availability groups. Is the below possible?

[image]

Answer (score 1):

> Can I use Server3 to host the AG groups of `Server1` and `Server2`.

Your scenario is possible. AG1 and AG2 should be different availability groups. Also, all the 3 servers should be part of same Windows cluster.

The only problem that I can see is if `server3` goes down (for whatever reason, blue screen, disk failure, or any disaster) then you will loose DR for `server1` and `server2` both at the same time. Also, `server3` when a failover occurs from both `server1` and `server2` should be powerful to support the load interms of CPU, DiskIO and Memory.